# How to embed a Google Chart Gantt chart into a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, gantt-chart

I currently keep my project plans in Google Sheets. I see now that Google has a   [Gantt Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) that can be directly embedded in a web page. I would like to embed the Gantt chart directly in a Google Sheet. The native Insert->Chart does not include a selection for the Gantt chart. Is there a way to use this control inside of Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Spreadsheets does not offer a built in Gantt Chart option. And Google Apps Script does not afford the capability to manipulate the UI in the way your link mentions. The best option I have found is to use the [SPARKLINE](https://trevorfox.com/2017/01/google-spreadsheets-sparkline-examples/) function to create interactive Gantt Charts with data from the spreadsheet.

`=SPARKLINE({daysSinceProjectStartUntilTaskStart, daysSinceProjectStartUntilTaskFinish})`

[image]

Here is a tutorial and demo: https://trevorfox.com/2017/01/google-spreadsheets-gantt-charts/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!